# How to integrate dovecot version 2 with gnus emacs

Tags: emacs, gnus, dovecot

I am trying to use emacs and gnus as a mail reader. There are several snippets of instructions online for how to do this with offlineimap and dovecot, however they seem to be for the earlier version of dovecot. I have successfully installed offlineimap and dovecot2 (using Archlinux pacman). I have both offlineimap and dovecot "working." I can retrieve my mail from my university's imap server using offlineimap. Dovecot starts and I can login to telnet localhost in a terminal. However, I have tried several commands in my .gnus.el file, but I am unable to achieve an integration with gnus that will allow gnus to find my local email folders. I have placed the local address of my Maildir in the dovecot configuration files.

Any advice or pointers would be appreciated. Please suggest any additional information that I should provide to assist in the diagnosis of my problem.

Comment: thank you Daimrod, you pointed me in the right direction, but I ended up doing something slightly different. I changed the maildir variable to include the layout argument, and in .gnus.el I did the following:`(setq imap-shell-method /usr/lib/dovecot/imap)` and `(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods '((nnimap "mail" (nnimap-stream shell))))`

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do it:

I use `getmail` and `offlineimap` to sync my mails into `~/mail/` in `Maildir` format.

I have `mail_location = maildir:~/mail:LAYOUT=fs` in my `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`.

and in my .gnus.el

`(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods '((nnimap "localhost"
                                               (nnimap-stream network))))`
Moreover, dovecot only listens to localhost.

Start Gnus with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`gnus`<kbd>RET</kbd>, browse servers
with <kbd>^</kbd>, select your server with <kbd>RET</kbd>, subscribe
and unsubscribe to your mailboxes with <kbd>U</kbd>.